# Sorting Dictionary Values : Error lambda

Tags: python, lambda, key

Hello everyone I have a question I'm trying to sort a dictionary by its value but I keep getting

```
Invalid Syntax Error
```

The error appears around `lambda` and `(k`

Heres what I have:

```
import string

my_dict = {'a' : 15, 'c' : 35, 'b' : 20}

for key, value in sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)):

    print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

I'm not nearly the best at python but I thought everything looks right.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening??

**UPDATE!!!!!!!!!**

As sugested I removed the brackets but now I'm getting errors

```
 for key, value in sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda k,v: v,k):
       print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

I dont know what this means:

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after arg
```

Comment: What version of python are you running? The above code runs for me in Python 2.7

Comment: Python 3.3.0, is there a more efficient way in this version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on jamylak's answer, since Python 3 does not have parameter unpacking, you need to use:

```
key=lambda item: (item[1], item[0])
```

As for why

```
for key, value in sorted(my_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda k,v: v,k):
```

fails with

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after arg
```

it's because the last `k` is interpreted as a third, non-keyword argument to `sorted()`. Your first attempt `key=lambda (k,v): (v,k)` was good, but only for Python 2, unfortunately.

Comment: And my understanding keeps on getting enlightened. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.0 doesn't support the lambda parameter unpacking.

Eg. You need

```
lambda x: x[0]
```

To access the first parameter

Also it's just `my_dict.items()`

Comment: Well that makes sense thanks for breaking it down for me. I guess the way to the solution varies from python version to python version.